# If $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$, then how is $\cos(\cos x) > \sin x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

If $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$, then

A) $\cos(\cos x) > \sin x$

B) $\sin(\sin x) > \sin x$

C) $\sin(\cos x) > \cos x$

D) $\cos(\sin x) > \sin x$

I have come across some such questions. How do you solve such questions in a short period of time. Usually, substitution of values helps in trigonometry questions, however, in this case, generally, what are the best values to substitute for $x$ and solve analytically? Is there some other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immediately options $B$ and $C$ can be eliminated, since it is a well known fact that, for all positive $\theta$, $\theta> \sin \theta\tag{1}$ Thus, options $A$ and $D$ have to be checked. It is easy to discard $D$ by putting $x=\frac {\pi}{2}$. Hence $A$ only is possible. This is of course a short-cut which will allow you to solve the problem easily. A rigorous proof of $A$ can thus be avoided. However, for completion, I shall write it down:
From $(1)$, we have $$\frac {\pi}{2}-x> \cos x$$
Since, $\cos x$ is a decreasing function, composing it to both sides would require us to change sign of inequality.
Hence $$\cos(\cos x)>\sin x$$

Comment: I did not try putting $\pi/2$ just because of the strict inequality. But thanks for the trick. That is all I needed.